# How to do probability question (v)? Why is my logic wrong?

Tags: probability

```
One plastic toy aeroplane is given away free in each 
packet of cornflakes. Equal numbers of red, yellow, 
green and blue aeroplanes are put into the packets.    

Henry, a quality controller employed by the cornflakes 
manufacturer, opens a number of packets chosen at random 
to check on the distribution of colours. 

Find the probability that 

(v)  the first two packets he opens have aeroplanes of different colours
```

For v:

Shouldnt it be 1/4 * 1/4 too because it is equal the proportion of different colors? Or 1/4 (color A) *3/4 (different color)= 3/16? Can someone explain to me why my logic is wrong?

Ans= 1 - ((1/4)^2)4 = 3/4

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{4}$ is the probability that the first plane is very specifically red and the second plane is yellow... but ignores all of the other possible color combinations it could have been which also count as two different colors.  $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}$ is the probability that the first plane is very specifically red and the second plane is a different color but ignores all of the other color combinations where the first plane was something different than red.

Comment: If you insist, you could write this as the probability the first plane is red and the second plane is not, **plus** the probability that the first plane is yellow and the second plane is not, **plus** the first plane is green and the second is not, etc... giving you $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$... or even easier, you just notice that regardless what the first plane's color was, there is a $\frac{3}{4}$ probability that the second plane is different, jumping straight to the final answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz how do I get better in math? If i make mistake like this does it mean I am bad at it?

Comment: Nice to be introduced to "Henry" for the second time (see [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731373)). Please, next time, group such questions.

Comment: "How do I get better at math?"  Wanting to get better is a good first step.  Motivation is central in learning and practicing any skill.  Beyond that, practice.  I must stress also the importance of *making mistakes*.  Making mistakes (*and seeing mistakes be made by other people*) is an excellent way to learn so long as you can identify or understand why they are mistakes (*even if it needs to be pointed out to you by someone else first*) so that you can better understand in what ways you could get a wrong answer and avoid them in the future.  Keep asking, keep making mistakes, keep trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it this way...

It doesn't matter which color the first one is. Whether that be red, yellow, green or blue, what matters is the *second* color. For any first color, there are $4-1=3$ other colors. Therefore, our probability is $1\cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$, because the $1$ signifies that any color works. The $\frac{3}{4}$ signifies the *other* three colors that can be chosen second. Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{\frac{3}{4}}$.

-FruDe

Comment: Thanks,how do I get better in math? If i make mistake like this does it mean I am bad at it? @FruDe

Comment: @Isabel Practice! And no, everyone makes mistakes while they are learning, and it is key to learning. Keep at it, and you will get the hang of it! By the way, if you found any of the answers helpful, you should click the green checkmark next to one to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Isabel of course not! Keep practicing, probability requires quite a bit of logic and reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer you posted (I think taken by your textbook) is self evident:

In  your [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731373/how-to-do-this-probability-question-iv) we saw that the probability to have the first two packets with two red aeroplanes is $(\frac{1}{4})^2$

that means that the  probability to have the first two packets with two  "same color" aeroplanes is $4 \cdot(\frac{1}{4})^2$

Thus the requested probability is the complement of the previous probability to 1, say

$1-4 \cdot(\frac{1}{4})^2=\frac{3}{4}$

EDIT: in your solution you found $\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{16}$

this means, for example: "Red" and "Not Red" but you have 4 different colors to chose, so if you multiply your solution times 4 you have the correct solution.

My answer was to  lead you to the nearest solution of the previous point you posted today.

Comment: @Isabel : read my edits. Now I hope it is clear